# Drawing Tools for drawing array/linked list images

Tags: data-structures, paint

I'm thinking of writing few blogs on arrays and linked list and for that I need some good drawing tool for drawing images to explain the concept and the logic. **I don't want to copy/paste images from other source** so if anyone among you knows about any such tool in which I can create images fast and similar to ones given in books and on other site, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that Google Docs Draw, could satisfy your needs.

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/03/drawing-in-google-docs.html

Answer (score 4):

Graphviz can draw linked data structures by using special "record" node shapes. Here's [one example](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/datastruct.html) which was automatically generated during a debug session.

Comment: Great! This tool helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use Omni Graffle for the sort of task you are describing.

http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/

Comment: looks good but its only for mac ... is there something equivalent for windows as well?

Comment: You know you've been looking for an excuse to buy an iPad... :)
Omni Graffle can export to PDF and JPEGs, so the output is cross-platform.

For Windows, you could probably use Visio or even PowerPoint in a pinch.